# How do i run GithHub actions .yaml files in certain order?

Tags: github, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions, action

I have two .yaml files for my GitHub actions. I need the second file to be executed only after first. How can I achieve this if the jobs are both in other files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [workflow_run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_runbranchesbranches-ignore) syntax for Github Actions workflows.

In the example below, a workflow with the following trigger will only run when the workflow named **Workflow Tester** is **completed** (you could also started them in sequence using the **requested** type).

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Workflow Tester"]
    types: [completed] #requested
```

Note that when using the trigger that way (with the **completed** type) you can also check the previous workflow, and perform different jobs depending on the workflow conclusion.

#### Example

```yaml
jobs:
  on-success:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    steps:
      [...]
  
  on-failure:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'failure' }}
    steps:
      [...]
```

I've tested this syntax [in this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/12-run-workflow.yml) if you want to have a look and check the workflow runs in the repo **Actions** tab.

Answer (score 6):

There is a feature called [Reusing Workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) which can be used.

Example:

- `workflow1.yaml`

```
name: Job1
on:
  workflow_call:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Job1 Executed!
```

- `workflow2.yaml`

```
name: Job2
on:
  workflow_call:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Job2 Executed!
```

- `demo1.yaml`(Calling Workflow)

```
name: Demo1
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  call-workflow1:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/workflow1.yaml
  call-workflow2:
    if: ${{ always() }} #This will make your workflow2 executed even if workflow1 fails, remove this, if you want to run this only on success of workflow1
    needs: call-workflow1
    uses: ./.github/workflows/workflow2.yaml
```

- Sample

[image: ActionExample]

Reference -

- [Job Link](https://github.com/thechetantalwar/demo-github-actions/actions/runs/2746972757)
- [Repo](https://github.com/thechetantalwar/demo-github-actions)